# Using Jlabel and JTextField array to display in certain format

Tags: java, netbeans-8

currently i am trying to get my Jtextfield and Jlabels to display in this format[image]

I currently only have the array for labels as for some reason they are just not displaying in the Jpanel when I have given them values.

```
private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[8]; // (8 = max capacity)
int idsCount = 6; // This value varies from 1 - 8 depending on user input

private void initIDLabels {
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        labels[i] = new JLabel();
        LabelFieldPanel.add(labels[i]);
    }
    changeLabelsVisibility();
}

private void changeLabelsVisibility() {
    for (JLabel label : labels) {
        label.setVisible(false);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < idsCount; i++) {
        labels[i] = idsArray[i];
        labels[i].setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Question 1: Why isn't it appearing in the Jpanel?
Question 2: How to make it display in that format is it even possible?

Comment: What is the contents of `idsArray`? Are they the labels text? If so, change `labels[i] = idsArray[i];` into `labels[i].setText(idsArray[i]);`

Comment: yes it is the labels text, right doing that way is possible too.

Comment: Are you adding this `LabelFieldPanel` to a `JFrame` and displaying it? Please add that part of the code to the question as well.

Comment: For this kind of a UI you can use `GridLayout`. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Comment: @Parsad Karunagoda I just drag and drop the Jpanel function into the JFrame so I have no idea of what code you meant.